# Integer to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert a number into a list of ints (preferably hex, but I know that's in my control via print formatting):

```
0xFFFF
```

should turn into:

```
[0xFF, 0xFF]
```

I will admit I am very confused about Python's ability to handle lower level information like bytes. I have been reading about `bytes`, `bytearray`, and similar methods for hours without being able to succeed at this task in a way that seems efficient. I am trying to understand how to do it in the most Pythonic and efficient way.

This is what I've come up with so far for string inputs:

```
>>> [ord(x) for x in '0xFFFF'.replace('0x','').decode('hex')]
[255, 255]
```

And int inputs:

```
>>> v = 0xFFFF
>>> [ord(x) for x in '{:04x}'.format(v).decode('hex')]
[255, 255]
```

I know the list can be formatted like this:

```
>>> a = list(ord(x) for x in '0xFFFF'.replace('0x','').decode('hex'))
>>>'[{}]'.format(', '.join([hex(x).upper() for x in a]))
'[0XFF, 0XFF]'
```

Is there a cleaner way to do the conversions and then output formatting? None of the questions or answers I've found on Stack Overflow or Google have matched this particular situation, but maybe I just missed something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I apologize - my original question did not exactly represent what I was trying to accomplish. In my quest to make a minimum reproducible example, I skipped something important: 0xFFFF should be able to be a number or a string. It's fine to do it in separate operations/functions.

Comment: If you were using Python 3, you could've done this with the built-in [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks. I'm not able to use Python 3 unfortunately.

Comment: `hex_list = [hex(i) for i in my_int_list]` Byte style isn't usefull, human readable issue !

Answer (score 3):

If you want to separate it by making group of some specific numbers of character then you can do it simply using textwrap's wrap function. In our case the number of characters in group is 2.

```
>>>from textwrap import wrap
>>>v = 0xFFFF
>>>print list('0x' + x.upper() for x in wrap(str(hex(v))[2:], 2))
>>>v = 0xFFFFF
>>>print list('0x' + x.upper() for x in wrap(str(hex(v))[2:], 2))
>>>print list(int('0x' + x, 16) for x in wrap(str(hex(v))[2:], 2))
```

Output:

```
>>>['0xFF', '0xFF']
>>>['0xFF', '0xFF', '0xF']
>>>[255, 255, 15]
```

****Note:** wrap function makes the group from starting of the string and if the length of string is not the multiple of the number of which we have to make groups, it will make group of remaining characters (as making groups from starting of the string) at last.*

Answer (score 2):

The formatting can be handled with the default string formatting in Python:

```
'[{}]'.format(', '.join(map('0x{:02X}'.format, a)))
```

`'{:02x}'` means that we print the number as a *hexadecimal* one (`x`), with at two *leading zeros* (`02`) if necessary.

As for the conversion from a string to a list of integers, the following is probably more elegant:

```
list(bytes.fromhex('0xFFFF'.replace('0x', '')))
```

for example:

```
>>> list(bytes.fromhex('0xFFFF'.replace('0x', '')))
[255, 255]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better way to do the conversion from int to list or is my solution appropriate?

Comment: @Anthony: see edit for a Python-3.x version. I would strongly advice migrating, since Python-2.x support will end within less than two years: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, my environment is not able to be updated as it is controlled very tightly by a third party. I am developing an application that is bound by Python 2.7.5 and it will not be updated in the foreseeable future.